# Вылетает программа при отправке почты. На всех компах кроме одного

Tags: c#, smtp

Написала первую в жизни программу на c# wpf с отправкой почты на outlook. С моего компа почта уходит нормально, а любого другого компа возникает ошибка и программа вылетает:

> Имя сбойного приложения: NUP.exe, версия: 1.0.0.0, метка времени: 0x5b51a634
>  Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия:
>   10.0.14393.0, метка времени: 0x57898e34
>  Код исключения: 0xe0434352
>  Смещение ошибки: 0x000d96c2
>  Идентификатор
>   сбойного процесса: 0x2b58
>  Время запуска сбойного приложения:
>   0x01d4224db09239a5
>  Путь сбойного приложения:
>   \172.23.100.14\nup\NUP.exe
>  Путь сбойного модуля:
>   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>  Идентификатор отчета:
>   f33e32fa-a659-4788-afaa-59192a17143e
>  Полное имя сбойного пакета: 
>   Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:

Вторая ошибка:

> Приложение: NUP.exe Версия платформы: v4.0.30319 Описание. Процесс был
>   завершен из-за необработанного исключения. Сведения об исключении:
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Код

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.myoutlook.ru", 587);
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
   string FromAddr = "from";
   string ToAddr = "to";
   bool EnableSSL = false;
   string Login = "login";
   string Password = "pass";
   Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");

   message.IsBodyHtml = false;
   message.SubjectEncoding = encoding;
   message.BodyEncoding = encoding;
   MessageBox.Show("From address: " + FromAddr);
   message.From = new MailAddress(FromAddr,  encoding);
   message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(ToAddr,  encoding));
   message.Subject = "Subject";
   message.Body = "Body";
   smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   smtp.EnableSsl = EnableSSL;
   MessageBox.Show("Enable SSL is: " + EnableSSL.ToString());
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Login) &&
       !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Login is " + Login);
       smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Login, Password);

   }
   smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
   smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: Вот же System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

Comment: Приводите полный текст ошибки, со стектрейсом. Наверное, потребуется добавить в приложение логгирование

Comment: Ну или поймать исключение в main))

Comment: Добавила логгирование. текст в логе:INFO 2018-07-23 02:22:18 – Серверу SMTP требовалось защищенное соединение, или подлинность клиента не была установлена. Отклик сервера: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Comment: Код, может быть? :D

Answer (score 0):

У вас в ошибке все написано:

> Серверу SMTP требовалось защищенное соединение, или подлинность
>   клиента не была установлена. Отклик сервера: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was
>   not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

А вы почему-то не включаеще защищенное соединение:

```
bool EnableSSL = false;
```

Comment: если включаю защищенное соединение то вообще ничего не отправляется и пишет ошибку "Удаленный сертификат недействителен согласно результатам проверки подлинности"

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в ограничении прав отправки почты с ящика-отправителя